# Comparing C# object

Tags: c#, string

Consider this code:

```
object str1 = "shahrooz";
object str2 = "shahrooz";
object int1 = 1;
object int2 = 1;

Console.WriteLine("str1 == str2 : " + (str1 == str2));
Console.WriteLine("int1 == int2 : " + (int1 == int2));
Console.ReadLine();
```

When you run this code you will get this result:

```
str1 == str2 : True
int1 == int2 : False
```

Both compare are object but why the first comparison returns true but second comparison returns false?

Comment: This is a guess, but strings get interned so likely that's what's happening to those object references compared to the Int32 objects being created for the numbers and you're doing a direct reference comparison. Hopefully someone can confirm this in a concrete answer?

Comment: You should read about boxing and unboxing. Integers are value-types and making them objects causes them to be wrapped internally to act like reference-types. So integers are compared by reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick and dirty check of memory addressing helps to shine light on this using this (grabbed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10861731/1250301)):

```
public static IntPtr GetAddress(object o)
{
    unsafe
    {
        TypedReference tr = __makeref(o);
        IntPtr ptr = **(IntPtr**)(&tr);
        return ptr;
    }
}
```

You can then do this:

```
Console.WriteLine(GetAddress(str1));
Console.WriteLine(GetAddress(str2)); 
Console.WriteLine(GetAddress(int1)); 
Console.WriteLine(GetAddress(int2));
```

I get:

```
35839968
35839968
35840128
35840152
```

What you should see is that the address of `str1` and `str2` are identical, and the address of `int1` and `int2` are different. This is because your strings are *interned* (because they are *string literals*).  A single copy of the string `shahrooz` is stored in memory and both `str1` and `str2` are referring to it. Your `int1` and `int2` on the other hand are being *boxed* which is taking the value type `int` and placing it inside an `object`. Each `int` (or any other value type) boxed gets put in its own box with its own address.

Now the default behavior of `==` when given two reference types (like `object`) is to just compare the memory address (to see if they refer to the same object), and this is what's happening. In the case of the strings, it's the same object. In the case of the ints, it isn't.

As others have suggested, using `Equals` will give the desired result because `Object.Equals` is `virtual` and can be overridden, hence calling the appropriate `int.Equals` when given `int` and `string.Equals` when given a string.

Answer (score 5):

The `==` operator performs a reference equality check if both operands are of type `object` or no more specific equality operator can be determined based on the **compile-time** types of the operands.

In your case the compile-time operand types are `object`, so reference equality is checked. At the time when you assigned `1` to either variable, the runtime "boxed" the value into an object. As a result you get two objects that contain the integer value one, but they are two separate objects, thus reference equality returns `false`.

To perform value equality comparison, use the `Equals()` method. It can be overridden in subclasses to perform type-specific value comparison, which I believe is what you want to do. The expression `int1.Equals(int2)` should return what you want. Since both variables are nullable, you might want to write it as `int1 != null ? int1.Equals(int2) : int2 == null` to prevent throwing NullReferenceException when `int1` is `null`.

Comment: As a note to your last paragraph, you can use the static method [`Object.Equals(int1, int2)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4hkze5k(v=vs.110).aspx), that static method will do proper unboxing and null checking and gives the same logical result as `int1 != null ? int1.Equals(int2) : int2 == null` (Well actually it does a `Object.RefrenceEquals(int1, int2)` and a `Object.RefrenceEquals(int1, null) || Object.RefrenceEquals(int2, null)` before the `int1.Equals(int2)`  so the logic is slightly different)

Answer (score 4):

Doing `(int1 == int2)` compares 2 objects, which are different, due to the CLR's boxing: when you put a ValueType inside a ReferenceType, .NET does boxing for you, so you get 2 different objects, each boxes the 1 value that you assigned.

To make the comparison work, you need to either store the 2 numbers in **int**s,
or do `((int)int1 == (int)int2)`

For info about boxing, see this article:
Boxing and Unboxing (C# Programming Guide)
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx

Comment: This code: `((int)int1 == (int)int2)` does not "store" the numbers in ints. It **casts** them as ints, which is entirely different.

Comment: Hi Alan. I wrote 2 options: The first option: store the 2 numbers in **int**s. And a second option: do `((int)int1 == (int)int2)`. You merged the two options for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53k8ybth.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

> For predefined value types, the equality operator (==) returns true if the values of its operands are equal, false otherwise. For reference types other than string, == returns true if its two operands refer to the same object. For the string type, == compares the values of the strings.

First time I misunderstood this quote, what it means actually is that there are 2 different operators in this case, one for object, and one for string.

The object operator compares the instance reference, and string operator compares the value of both strings.

In this case

```
Console.WriteLine(str1 == str2); // True, becuase of compiler optimizations.
// you can test it with:
Console.WriteLine(object.ReferenceEquals(str1, str2)); // this is true
```

But if you do

```
object s1 = "shahrooz";
object s2 = "shah";
s2 += "rooz";

Console.WriteLine(s1 == s2);
//You get false, becuase compiler now can't optimize this.
```

Said that

```
int1 == int2 // False, because they reference a different instance
int1 == int1 // True, same instance.
```

Comment: This is still not right, because he is compareing `==` on object and `==` is not virtual. Try `object str2 = "shah" + Console.ReadLine();` and type in `rooz`, you get false.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain if this is wrong then why is it documented in msd.microsoft?, I have not tested what you say but this is what microsoft says

Comment: @ScottChamberlain has the most correct answer. The types being referenced by the object variables are immaterial. Only the actual memory addresses being allocated are being compared. The only reason that the string references are reporting as equal is due to the compiler optimization.

Comment: Because you are misunderstanding the documentation. The quote you posted only applies if the two side types is of type `string`, if one is of type `object` you get the object `==` operator.

Comment: @AlanMcBee after some tests you both were right I updated

Answer (score 2):

It is because operators can't be `virtual`, because of that you are calling the `==` operator on `Object`.

The `==` operator for object compares references. For structs (like `int`) when cast to a `object` it will "box" the struct in to a class reference. The code

```
object int1 = 1;
object int2 = 1;
```

causes two boxes to be made so when you call `==` on the box it sees the other side is not the same box so it returns false.

Strings are already reference types so they don't get a extra box made when they are put in to a `object`. However the compiler treats them special, in the following code

```
object str1 = "shahrooz";
object str2 = "shahrooz";
```

The compiler only makes one `shahrooz` string in memory and assigns it to both `str1` and `str2`. This is why it returns `true` when you compare them.

If you did the code

```
public static void Main()
{
    object str1 = "shahrooz";
    object str2 = "shah" + Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine(str1 == str2);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

and typed in `rooz` you would get `false` as your result because you now have two different string references even though they have the same string content.

use the method `Equals` instead of `==`, that does check if the `Equals` method was overloaded on derived classes and will unbox structs to compare them.

Answer (score 0):

It is because `string` is immutable and they point to same references from string intern pool and its not true for any other value type or reference types as they create new references every time you initialize a new object.

To prove above we check references of two strings initialized separately:

```
object str1 = "shahrooz";
object str2 = "shahrooz";

Console.WriteLine(object.ReferenceEquals(str1, str2)); //True
Console.WriteLine(object.ReferenceEquals(int1, int2)); //False
```

Which proves that same strings hold same reference but other objects don't. Its not true for all the reference types but strings are treated as special classes.

On the other hand for any other reference types:

```
Test a = new Test { Num=1, Str="shahrooz"};
Test b = new Test { Num=1, Str="shahrooz"};

a.Equals(b); //False  
object.ReferenceEquals(a,b);  //False
```

But if you do,

```
Test c = a;
a.Equals(c); //True 
object.ReferenceEquals(a,c) //True.
```

Comment: THIS IS NOT A GOOD ANSWER. Notice that the OP is not comparing integers. It's not clear from reading the OP's question that it's actually comparing "references to integers" -- it looks like it is actually comparing integers that happen to be boxed. The "integer" comparison is actually comparing two objects, which happened to be named "int1" and "int2".

Comment: Any object which is not string, be it integer or object, they will hold different references. But strings return the references from string intern pool which tend to be exactly same all the time for same string.

Comment: It doesn't matter that the references are the same for strings, because they overload the Equals method.

Comment: @AlanMcBee Actually, that is a compiler optimization. Do `"shah" + Console.ReadLine()` and type in `rooz` and you get false.

Comment: @AlanMcBeeL It isn't true. Its false! Anyways I don't get your point.

Comment: Okay -- got carried away. You're right. Too late to delete my comment.

Comment: @AlanMcBee: Check the updated answer. Wait for your reply on that. Don't be too hasty to judge.

Comment: @AlanMcBee The compile time type of the expressions is `object`, so no, it won't use the overloaded `==` operator.

Comment: Yeah. I replied too quickly. I do know better.