# C#, How do I get back my object

Tags: c#, reflection, garbage-collection

```
public class testClass
{
    testClass x = null;
    public testClass()
    {
        x = this;
    }
    ~testClass()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("I was destroyed");
    }
}
public static class objectInMemory
{
    public static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        testClass a = new testClass();
        a = null;
        System.Console.WriteLine("a=null");
        System.Console.WriteLine("something");
        System.Console.WriteLine("last line");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

So.. In the code, how can I assign the instantiated testClass object to another variable after "a = null;" For example let "b = thatObject'sAddress;"?

It is not a problem, just came across my mind.

Comment: _Testclass b = a;_ ? but before setting a to null.

Comment: `a` is single reference you have. And after `a = null` you lost it

Answer (score 0):

You could use this to get a pointer to your object and use the debugger to check what you want to know:

[Memory address of an object in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994277/memory-address-of-an-object-in-c-sharp)

Garbage Collector basics can be looked up here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals