# How do I get the address inside the reference of an object

Tags: c#

I have a class called Person

```
class Person
{
    public string name;
    public int age;

    public Person(string name, int age)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

I created an object.

`Person person = new Person("Sam", 20);`

Now I want to print the address inside the person reference.

Now if anyone is thinking what I want to do with the address I just want to understand the concept of references.

By concept of references I mean

- Does a reference variable (here, person) contains address of the object.
- If it does contain the address than I want to know it's value.

Comment: You never defined an 'address' variable in your class, you can access 'name' or 'age' like this `person.name` / `person.age`, you cannot however access an object that doesn't exist; we're programmers not wizards!

Comment: Are you asking about memory address? Or address of where this person lives?

Comment: What's "the address"?  What "concept" of references are you trying to understand?

Comment: If you mean "the memory address of the object", [that's not something you can easily do](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4994277/4137916) -- and that's entirely on purpose, since managed objects can move.

Comment: Just FYI, you shouldn't need to know the actual memory address of an object to understand how references work. At least I never did. :)

Comment: You want to print the address of a *reference*? This means the adress of an adress. I suppose you want the address of the *instance*, don´t you? Anyway there´s not much use for this address in .NET. Why do you even care on it?

Comment: It will be more useful to read a good tutorial [Value vs Reference Types](http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx)

Comment: I want to print the address of the object whose reference is person. And I want to know does a reference contains an address.

Answer (score -2):

I think this is what you need:

```
&person -> gives you the pointer to the person variable
```

Try reading through this and see if it helps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/unsafe-code-pointers/

Comment: That will give you the address of the `person` variable, not the address of the object that the person variable refers to.

Comment: Just typing the code you've provided will give a compile error: `Cannot take the address of, get the size of, or declare a pointer to a managed type ('Person')`

Comment: But I want the address of the object that person variable refers to.