# C# Memory address extension with code

Tags: c#

I got following MemoryAddressExtenstion code, it shows object address in C#

Want to know what is

```
IntPtr**
```

and

```
**(IntPtr**)
```

Thanks

```
public static class MemoryAddressExtenstion
{
    public static string Address(this object me)
    {
        unsafe
        {
            TypedReference tr = __makeref(me);
            var ptr = **(IntPtr**)&tr;
            return "0x" + ptr.ToString("X");
        }
    }
}
```

[Variable Address](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/unsafe-code-pointers/how-to-obtain-the-address-of-a-variable)

[__makeref](http://benbowen.blog/post/fun_with_makeref/)

[TypedReference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.typedreference(v=vs.110).aspx)

[Source Code](https://github.com/supershowwei/stringpool.lab)

Comment: Where did you took that code from?

Comment: To understand that i'd suggest you look up on pointers in C++, that'll help you undertsand it since it's way more common in C / C++ than in C#. the `**` indicates a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: If anyone is wondering what on earth `__makeref` is, look [`here`](http://benbowen.blog/post/fun_with_makeref/).

Comment: updated with github source code

Comment: @MatthewWatson, thanks i put it in reference too

Comment: Pointer to a pointer to an address, this stuff used to empty half the Programming 101 class before they switched to Java.  The makeref creates a pointer to me, the & operator produces its address.  The first IntPtr* dereference produces the address of the caller's variable.    The second IntPtr* dereference digs out pointer of the object reference stored in that variable, the address in the GC heap.  It is dangerous code, the object is not pinned so it can crash with an AVE when a garbage collection occurs at the exact moment this code runs.  Very low odds, not zero. Okayish in debug code.

Comment: @HansPassant "Pointer to a pointer to an address, this stuff used to empty half the Programming 101 class..." made me chuckle a bit.  I had an instructor in my assembly class who's first statement was "Half of you will fail this class; no one will get an A" - he made the first part happen, the second, well let's just say we had one student who got at least 4.0 (all A's) in every class she ever took over the 4 years before she graduated with 5 STEM majors.(while holding a full time job at night)

Comment: `unsafe` - yep, agree with that part :)

Answer (score 3):

Sadly I can't explain them in a better way... So if someone can correct me then thanks!

What in .NET is called a "reference", in C would be called a "pointer". So what is called `object me` in C#, would be a `void *me`, a pointer (called `me`) to an object.

```
TypedReference tr = __makeref(me);
```

This creates a `TypedReference` to the variable `me`. As I've said, a reference is very similar to a C pointer (and in fact if you take a look at is [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/typedreference.cs,fa749891bb84425e) you will see that it contains a `IntPtr Value`). So in C it would be:

```
void **tr = &me;
```

(in .NET a pointer to a `TypedReference`, in C a pointer to a pointer)

Now the code is creating a third level of indirectness

```
void ***temp = &tr;
```

And then it is dereferencing it twice

```
void *ptr = **temp;
```

So we have a `*ptr` that is the same as the initial `*me`. We are doing it this way because normally in C# you can't directly convert a reference to the equivalent pointer.

Why are they doing this? Because you normally can't cast a reference to a pointer (you can't `(IntPtr)me`), nor you can take directly the address of reference (so you can't `&me`). But you can create a `TypedRefence` that is equivalent to doing `&me`. Now, sadly you can't do `(IntPtr*)tr`, or `(IntPtr)tr`. But fortunately you can `&tr`. Now finally you have been able to obtain a real pointer, and you can begin derefencing it to return to the initial pointer that you want.

Comment: An important point is that the `TypedReference` struct returned from `__makeref()` contains as its first field an `IntPtr` named `Value` that points to the object of interest, so the cast winds up with that value. (See [the implementation of `TypedReference`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/typedreference.cs,fa749891bb84425e).) If Microsoft changed the layout of `TypedReference` by adding a new field in front of the `Value` field, the cast would no longer return the correct value.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Yep. I imagined it was that way but I hadn't taken a look. As always, doing undocumented things is like playing with fate.

Answer (score 1):

`**` Is commonly used in C / C++ to point to a pointer. `IntPtr**` asks for a pointer to a pointer to a `IntPtr`

`**(IntPtr**)&tr;` references to the above mentioned structure.

It is Possible to use those in C#, see [pointers in C#](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/pointers-in-C-Sharp/) but I suggest to learn more about this you should read up on C++ / C since it is more common in those languages.

Comment: @Amit yeah I know there are pointers in C# but rather uncommon. That's why I suggested to read up on C / C++ to learn more about it since it's more common there.

Comment: @Amit Thanks for letting me know, I added your link to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from the beginning, an `IntPtr` is a [struct that represents a memory address](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54170619/184528).

The `*` after a type-name means type that is a pointer to the preceding type. So `IntPtr*` means pointer to `IntPtr`. And `IntPtr**` means a pointer to a pointer to an `IntPtr`.

When a type is in parenthesis before an expression it is a type-cast operation. So `(IntPtr**)x` means cast `x` to a `IntPtr**`.

The `&` operator is the [address-of operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/and-operator). So `&tr` means get the address of the value `tr`. Because `tr` is of type [`TypedReference`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.typedreference?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) the resulting value has type pointer to `TypedReference*`.

The `*` operator at the front of the expression is the [dereference operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/multiplication-operator), which returns the value at a given address. So `*x` is get the value at the memory location pointed to by `x`. And `**x` is get the value at the memory location pointed to at `*x`. This implies that x is a pointer to a pointer.

At first glance though, this should produce garbage. We are converting from a `TypedReference*` to a `IntPtr**`. It works only because the [first field in a `TypedReference` is in fact an `IntPtr`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/typedreference.cs), which points to the original object.

In general this is a dangerous little trick, which should be used with great caution because:

- memory addresses of objects move (you can use `GCHandle.Alloc` or the `fixed` keyword to pin them)
- `__makref` is an undocumented and unsupported part of the language
- this depends on implementation details of `TypedRef`
- it is not portable code