# In C# is there a way to write the CPU registers during a CLR exception?

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I have the stack during an exception but some times I need the CPU registers to isolate the issue. Is there a way to dump the registers or at least EIP during an exception?

Comment: Your title says "write" but your question body implies being able to read=fetch=dump.  Which do you mean?

Comment: It seems clear to me that OP means to read from the registers. If they said "write to" I could see the confusion, but they didn't. They meant "write" as in "display". I just don't see how that information might be helpful. You'd have to compensate for whatever nonsense the jitter is doing somehow. Maybe this is some super special case that I just can't imagine though.

Comment: yes I mean like Trace.Write, with the registers in complex functions I can know exactly what object is null or other helpful details

Comment: I'm not sure you're familiar with CPU registers. How will they tell you what object is null?

Comment: See following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994277/memory-address-of-an-object-in-c-sharp