# How does these lazy inline string-locks actually work, do they work, do they cause problem?

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

So, I've been using strings as "uniquely identifiable mutexes", but I'm not sure if they're having the effect I intended them to have and now I'm having problems

I'm working in a multi-threaded application here and I'm facing weird behavior with my locks and I want to make sure that it's "Dumb locking" instead of "using dumb locks"

My locks look like this

```
private Stuff _stuff = null;
public Stuff Stuff {
    get {
        lock($"{this.SomeIdentifier}_stuff_initialization") {
            if(stuff == null) {
                stuff = new Stuff();
                stuff.DoLazyInitialization(this.SomeOtherLazyInitedStuff);
                return stuff;
            } else {
                return stuff;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Too trash? Works? What should I be aware of when writing this type of code?

Comment: My guess will be that it is not working, but i can not back it up. I would rewrite it to use Lazy, ConcurrentDictionary or MemoryCache instead - which would be fairly easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are problems using strings as mutexes for locking and a very good answer here:

[Using string as a lock to do thread synchronization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192969/using-string-as-a-lock-to-do-thread-synchronization)

In addition to that, there may be an issue with your logic.  If the 'SomeIdentifier' is mutable, then you run into the possible race condition where:

Thread A calls `get` on object instance 1

Thread B updates `SomeIdentifer` on object instance 1

Thread A locks and instantiates `stuff` on object instance 1

Thread B calls `get` on object instance 1 (locks on a different string)

Thread A calls `DoLazyInitialization`

Thread B returns 'stuff' (as it is not null) prior to `DoLazyInitialization` completing.

Comment: So, the 'same thing but different instance' issue is a different thing and I don't think that locking is what you need for that.  What you are looking for in that instance is some kind of concurrency check in your underlying data store - you won't be able to solve that via a lock I don't think.

Comment: True, for a larger scale definitely; Currently there is 1 application accessing a lot of databases and it has been more than enough processing wise, the program is just a "glorified put this JSON in the RDBMS" no heavy duty; I also use these lame locks for memory caches, someone gave a good tip in the comments right above, I just didn't know those were a thing.

Comment: Large or small scale, I think the DB is the way to do this.  Solving concurrency in your multi threaded C# code is a considerably more difficult thing to get completely right - good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I have found out (the hard way) that actually locking with $ string is pretty bad, it does NOT work.

This is the code I used for testing:

```
object o = new object();
Parallel.For(0, 1000, (i) => {
    lock (o) {
        Console.WriteLine($"Hey {i}");
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }
});
```

It looks dumb because it is a silly test and what is expected happens: It locks the region correctly.

**The following also works**

```
var lid = "SomeId";
Parallel.For(0, 1000, (i) => {
    lock(lid) {
        Console.WriteLine($"Hey {i}");
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }
});

Parallel.For(0, 1000, (i) => {
    lock("SomeId") {
        Console.WriteLine($"Hey {i}");
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }
});
```

Now if you try to compose the string on the fly and use it as a locking mutex, it won't lock properly, it will generate many different instances of the same string and you'll get multiple different "locks" allowing different threads to access the resource.

**This does not work**

```
var lid = "SomeId";
Parallel.For(0, 1000, (i) => {
    lock($"{lid}_LOCKING") {
        Console.WriteLine($"Hey {i}");
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }
});

var lid = "SomeId";
Parallel.For(0, 1000, (i) => {
    lock(lid + "_LOCKING") {
        Console.WriteLine($"Hey {i}");
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }
});
```

The code below works, but I would avoid if the dynamic expression may generate way too many unique strings:

var lid = "SomeId";
Parallel.For(0, 1000, (i) => {
    lock(String.Intern($"{lid}_LOCKING")) {
        Console.WriteLine($"Hey {i}");
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }
});

I might have been lazy to test it this way before, but now I see it clearly it's a dumb way to lock. Do not lock with non-constant strings, even if the string components used in creating that string are immutable, it does not work;

Comment: You can solve this problem with `lock (String.Intern($"{lid}_LOCKING"))`.