# Why does my program crash with an invalid json primitive error?

Tags: c#, json, runtime-error

I'm making a flight controller program in C# and this receives data function, the program will run as intended for around 2 minutes before the program crashes and returns the error invalid JSON primitive. I've tried googling around and can't find anything about my issue, as I can't see any problems with the program. The function that deserializes the JSON is here, this is also the line that causes the error and returns the invalid JSON primitive message.

```
void ReceiveData() //This function is used to listen for messages from the flight simulator
{
    while (true)
    {
        NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream(); //sets the network stream to the client's stream
        byte[] buffer = new byte[256]; //Defines the max amount of bytes that can be sent

        int bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            string jsonreceived = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead); //Converts the received data into ASCII for the json variable
            JavaScriptSerializer Deserializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            TelemetryUpdate telemetry = Deserializer.Deserialize<TelemetryUpdate>(jsonreceived);
            this.Invoke(new Action(() => { TelemetryReceivedLabel.Text = jsonreceived; })) ;
            Updatelabels(telemetry); //runs the update labels function with the telemetry data as an argument

            lock (@"c:\temp\BlackBox.txt")
            {
                File.AppendAllText(@"c:\temp\BlackBox.txt", "Data Received" + jsonreceived + DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt") + Environment.NewLine); //this appends the json data to the blackbox file
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The program works completely fine and passes information into variables how I want it too like this I have logged the JSON data t check if the variable names match etc. they all fit correctly.

```
void Updatelabels(TelemetryUpdate telemetry) //this function updates all the labels with received data
{
    if (this.InvokeRequired) //invokes the telemetryupdatedelegate
    {
        this.Invoke(new TelemetryUpdateDelegate(Updatelabels), telemetry);
        return;
    }
    
    altitudelabel.Text = string.Format("{0:0.00}", telemetry.Altitude);
    speedlabel.Text = string.Format("{0:0.00}", telemetry.Speed);
    pitchlabel.Text = string.Format("{0:0.00}", telemetry.Pitch);
    verticalspeedlabel.Text = string.Format("{0:0.00}", telemetry.VerticalSpeed);
    throttlelabel.Text = string.Format("{0:0.00}", telemetry.Throttle);
    elevatorspeedlabel.Text = string.Format("{0:0.00}", telemetry.ElevatorPitch);

    WarningUpdateEvent?.Invoke(telemetry); //invokes the warning update event
    ReceivedDataGrid.Rows.Insert(0,telemetry.Altitude, telemetry.Speed, telemetry.Pitch, telemetry.VerticalSpeed, telemetry.Throttle, telemetry.ElevatorPitch, telemetry.WarningCode); //populates the datagrid with the received data
    ReceivedDataGrid.AutoResizeColumns(); //resizes the columns to fit properly
}
```

Comment: What if there is more data in your stream than 256 bytes? If so, the JSON would be incomplete and invalid. Would [ReadToEnd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.readtoend?view=net-7.0) work for you?

Comment: @SimonWilson i tried that i increased it to 2048 byte and the program lasts around a minute longer than previously. however it still ends up crashing with the same error

Comment: then obviously the stream you are reading is getting larger on each call...what is `client`? the object you get the stream from? All I can think is, as you are appending all text to a file, the stream source may also be doing the same, as in reading from another source that is growing, such as an appended file. (does this make sense?)

Comment: Another thing to try....kick out your `jsonreceived` value to a text file...see what is being returned and then examine it.

Comment: @SimonWilson I've tried that too and I can't see anything specifically that stands out as irregular.

Comment: @roadgh1256 JavaScriptSerializer was obsolete many years ago. Doesn't make any sense to try to fix something. Why don't you try Newtonsoft.Json for example?

Comment: @Serge its a school project, it has to be done according to the set way they provided. I'm still getting the issue as well and no idea why

Comment: `lock (@"c:\temp\BlackBox.txt")`  I'm worried that you think this does something other than what it [actually does](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4193016/1563833).

Comment: @Wyck it locks the file, i have multiple threads and functions writing to one file an it would crash with a cross thread operation error, having the lock stopped it crashing

Comment: @roadgh1256, each thread is locking the same object and thus coordinating your threads.  But the object you chose has ***nothing*** to do with the file or its filename.  You can lock *any* **object** in .NET.  You're locking a particular string (strings are objects).  It just so happens that in .NET, strings with the same content are also _the same object_, so locking a string is actually locking the one-and-only object associated with that string.  But, IMO, It's better to explicitly create an object `object myLock = new object();` and then call `lock (myLock)`. I hope you understand that.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to stem from a memory leak relating to the datagrid.

Comment: this is better to fit as comment rather than an answer